# Unable To Reference Views in NavigationView Header Layout Android Development

Tags: android, kotlin

I have been trying to reference views in my NavigationView in my Activity using view binidng

So i have the following code in my XML

```
 <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".UsActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

  <include
      android:id="@+id/dashboard_home"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      layout="@layout/home_us"/>

  <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="start"
      android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
      >

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        >

      <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/grey_stroke_128dp_corners"
            android:elevation="20dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="5sp"
            android:paddingHorizontal="25dp"
            android:paddingVertical="13dp"
            android:text="Sign out"
            android:textColor="#d7111111"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView31"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/activity_us_nav_view"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/activity_us_nav_view" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView31"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/green_background_128dp_corners"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="5sp"
            android:paddingHorizontal="65dp"
            android:paddingVertical="13sp"
            android:text="Go back"
            android:textColor="#ebffffff"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView10"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView10"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView10" />


        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/activity_us_nav_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_layout"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView10"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/nav_drawer_menu" />


      </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


  </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>





</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And in my activity i have the following code

```
 val headerView: View = binding.activityUsNavView.getHeaderView(0)
 val headerBinding: NavHeaderLayoutBinding = NavHeaderLayoutBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(headerView.context))
```

But when i try to reference a view using the following code:

```
headerBinding.navHeaderCloseImageView.setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.atm))
```

Nothing changes or if i try setting any other view dynamically from my activity

What do you think i am doing wrong guys?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
      android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="start"
      android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
      app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
      app:menu=​"@menu/navigation"
      >
```

And the @layout/drawer_header will be the place holder of the views you want to add.

And then inflate first the view of the drawer and then add the headerView like:

```
binding.navigationDrawer.addHeaderView(headerBinding.root)
```

Let me know if it works

Check this article also as reference : https://medium.com/pragmatic-programmers/add-the-navigation-drawer-b1b1af1a65cb